# Continuous compile time I get error 90% after opencvde make command. More information is available

Tags: java, opencv

[ 91%] Generate files for Java bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fcemtopall/Masaüstü/opencv-3.4.1/modules/java/generator/../generator/gen_java.py", line 1093, in 
    copy_java_files(java_files_dir, target_path)
  File "/home/fcemtopall/Masaüstü/opencv-3.4.1/modules/java/generator/../generator/gen_java.py", line 1032, in copy_java_files
    src = checkFileRemap(java_file)
  File "/home/fcemtopall/Masaüstü/opencv-3.4.1/modules/java/generator/../generator/gen_java.py", line 25, in checkFileRemap
    assert path[-3:] != '.in', path
AssertionError: /home/fcemtopall/Masaüstü/opencv-3.4.1/modules/java/generator/src/java/org/opencv/osgi/OpenCVNativeLoader.java.in
modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/build.make:315: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dephelper/gen_opencv_java_source' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dephelper/gen_opencv_java_source] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2686: recipe for target 'modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with OpenCV, so the solution is in two ways:

1. Open `modules/java/generator/gen_java.py` file and edit the line `1029` from

re_package = re.compile(r'^package +(.+);$')

to

```
re_package = re.compile(r'^package +(.+);')
```

2. Or just redownload the source and it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with your path.

`/home/fcemtopall/Masaüstü/opencv-3.4.1/modules/java/generator/src/java/org/opencv/osgi/OpenCVNativeLoader.java.in`

Masaüstü

See this two U letters which are from another language. This might interpret a compilation issue when trying to generate JNI.

Try creating another directory under home such as /home/abc and compile from there.